# Made changes to robots.txt but search engines still say description not available

Tags: search, web, robots.txt

Most of the questions I see are trying to hide the site from being indexed by search engines.  For myself, I'm attempting the opposite.

For the robots.txt file, I've put the following:

```
# robots.txt 
User-agent: *
Allow: /   
# End robots.txt file
```

To me, this means that the search engines are allowed to search the directory. However, when I test it out it still displays the website as "A description for this result is not available because of this site's robots.txt"  but when I clicked on the link, it's displaying the above code.

I'm guessing it's because it takes awhile for Google and Bing to catch up? Or am I doing something wrong?

If it's because they haven't caught up to the changes made yet (these changes were made yesterday afternoon), then does anyone have a rough estimate to when the changes will be reflected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, it takes some time until search engines crawl your pages resp. your robots.txt again. There can be no serious estimate, as it depends on too many factors. Some search engines offer a service in their webmaster tools to recrawl specific pages, but there is no guarantee that this happens shortly.

Note that your robots.txt is equivalent to:

```
# robots.txt 
User-agent: *
Disallow:  
# End robots.txt file
```

(Many parsers know/understand `Allow`, but it is not part of the [original robots.txt specification](http://www.robotstxt.org/orig.html).)

And this robots.txt is equivalent to no robots.txt at all (or an empty robots.txt), because `Disallow:` (= allowing *all* URLs) is the default.